# Custom person account field appears locked

Tags: person-accounts

we are using person accounts. There is custom person account field date of birth that appears locked for one of the profiles. The field is not read only on layout. I cant see this field in field accessibility.

Please suggest why does it appear locked?

Comment: Are you using the NPSP? On which profile is the field locked? Is this a custom field on Contacts or on Accounts? If you're not using the NPSP, have you checked the field in both contacts and accounts since they're tied together and displayed on one page layout?

Comment: The field is locked on custom profile. We are using person accounts

Answer (score 0):

Check the Field Level Security FLS on that field and make sure it is editable by that custom profile.

Answer (score 0):

Since person accounts access both the Account and the Contact Objects and we don't know which of those objects this field exist in, you'll want to check the Field Level Security (FLS) settings of your custom profile using the Profile Editor on both of them until you find the problematic field, then update it's settings to give users with that profile edit permissions.

Unlike the NPSP, I don't believe that when person accounts are enabled on the native platform there's an additional relationship object involved that you'd need to change any permissions on.